# google.script.run returns undefined array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to return an array from my server side function getPrepList(). When accessing from the client side 'prepList[]' returns 'undefined'. This is just a snippet of the full code.gs file.

//< code.gs >//

```
function getPrepList(){
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var doPrepRange = sheet.getRange('F:F');
   var itemNameRange = sheet.getRange('A:A');
   var prepList = new Array();

    for(var i = 1; i < getFirstEmptyRow(); i++){
      if(doPrepRange.getCell(i,1).getValue() == true){
        prepList.push(itemNameRange.getCell(i, 1).getValue());
      };
    };
    Logger.log(prepList);
   return(prepList);
 };


function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
};
```

// < index.html > //

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><div align="center">PREP LIST MAKER v 2.0</h1></div>

    <button align="center" onClick="createCountSheet()">Nightly Count Sheet</button><br />
    <button align="center" onClick="showPrepList()">Get Prep List</button><br />

    <script>

    console.info("before execution");
    function createCountSheet(){
      google.script.run
        .generateCountSheet();
     };

     google.script.run 
       .withSuccessHandler(showPrepList)
       .getPrepList();

    function showPrepList(prepList){
      console.log(prepList);
    };

     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what types of data do you expect to find in the return value? How much data? Have you reviewed the allowed types?

Comment: I am returning all string primatives which are allowed per Google's documentation. The return size depends on the how many rows in the decalred ranges are returned 'true'.

Comment: Consider stringifying large data before sending, and then parsing after receiving: `return JSON.stringify(myData);` .... `myData = JSON.parse(receivedInput);` Also note that your server code is horrendously slow due to repeated use of the Spreadsheet Service (you call `getValue` and `getCell` in a loop when you could just work with an in-memory array).

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function getPrepList(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();;
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vals=rg.getValues();
  var prepList=[];
  for(var i=1;i<vals.length;i++){
    if(vals[i][5]){
      prepList.push(vals[i][0]);
    }
  }
  return prepList;
}
```

It's not clear to me what sheet you wanted so I just picked the active one.  I assumed you have a header row so I started the loop at one instead of zero.  By the way I did not test this so you may have to tweak it a little.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I am not having a problem with anything in ' code.gs'. The getPrepList function, when running server side, returns the correct values. 

The problem I have been having is with retrieving the array client side via 'google.script.run'.  My intuition (and very limited expereince) is that this is some kind of "async" issue that I tried to remedy with the 'withSuccessHandler' callback function in 'index.html'.

Comment: There are restrictions on what you can passed between client and server you might wanna check them in the guide section

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling `showPrepList(prepList)` from a button,

```
<button align="center" onClick="showPrepList()">Get Prep List</button><br />
```

`prepList` will be `undefined`, because you aren't passing any argument as `prepList`.

Try,

```
<button align="center" onClick="showPrepListFromSheet()">Get Prep List</button><br />

<script>

console.info("before execution");
 function showPrepListFromSheet(){
 google.script.run 
   .withSuccessHandler(showPrepList)
   .getPrepList();
function showPrepList(prepList){
  console.log(prepList);
};
}</script>
```

#### To read:

- [Html Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)
- [Server code Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)